# Android Device Monitor not showing emulator file explore

Tags: android, sqlite

I use the correct process to open Android Device Monitor in Android Studio 2.2.2 
I start the emulator go to Tools select ADM stop debugging. I get the same view as this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669652/android-device-monitor-file-explorer-not-working-whit-emulator) 
I have tried the reset I am about to give up on using ADM to look at a database
and use DB Browser except I have no idea where these data/data/ ? files are located on my hard drive
So my question's are 
First how do I fix the issue with the Android Device Monitor?
Second if the ADM issue can not be resolved where are the data files for a project so I can point DB Browser to these files?
NO I have not downloade DB Browser YET!

Comment: Where is this about?

Comment: @greenapps Do You Have Android Studio and have you ever written a project with a SQLite database ?

Comment: You did not answer my question. `how do I fix the issue with the Android Device Monitor?` Which issue? Where are you talking about?

Comment: @greenapps If you look James_Duh is asking the same question you are asking him to answer? At any rate see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James_Duh I have no idea why this works. That said it might be nice if someone can enlighten both of us. I have this issue with a project Emulator Nexus 5X     API level 25 Android 7.1.1 The project SDK 24 and build tools 24.0.3

So here is my fix
I created a New Emulator Nexus 4 with API level 22 Android 6.0 loaded the same project that would not show File Explore information in Android Devise Monitor with the Nexes 5X configuration and low and behold the File Explore information is displayed with the Nexus 4 configuration.

Bonus answer I think not sure as I have not tried to use DB Manager some old posts that go back to the days before Android Studio state you can not obtain database file on your hard drive! I suggest we both look at this closer
Because I can not post questions you might ask if someone here can explain why you need to have a device with API 23 to use ADM ? ?